# Convert existing database to Database project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, version-control

I have a MS-SQL database on a server and have decided to play around with source control for the database. I want to create a database project and include that project within my solution. Is there any way to "import" an existing database into a database project in Visual Studio 2008?

I have run a few searches but I haven't really found anything of substance yet. Any ideas will be welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you have Visual Studio 2008 Team System, then the Database Edition GDR release 2 add-on is the way to go.

You can download from here: [Microsoft® Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en)

You can find a list of features [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/11/25/visual-studio-team-system-2008-database-edition-gdr-rtm.aspx).

Also, [Introducing New Features In The VSTS Database Edition GDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483214.aspx)

**Update**: In response to poster's comment about not having the Team System version, you can still use the original Database Project that comes with Visual Studio, but it is not as fully featured as the new GDR R2 version.

Comment: awesome answer but sadly no Team System. Any other ideas? still +1 though :)

Comment: going to mark this as the answer since no one else has provided one. Thanks man